# Dynamic 3d object modeling

Tags: augmented-reality

I am developing an augmented reality application where it recognizes objects and change the colors. Can I use Vuforia SDK for this or are there any other better sdks to be used ?

and are there any good APIS for dynamic 3d object modelings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marker detection is does not depends on colour, it is depend on Histogram value. Its openGL image processing.

Every marker is treated by its grayscale value so whatever will be the color its doesn't matter. only you require is **" Sharp Curves on Image"** which you are treating as marker. As per I know:

---

**ATTRIBUTES FOR IDEAL IMAGE TARGETS**

---

**1.1.1 Features**

A feature is a sharp, spiked, chiseled detail in the image, such as the ones present in textured objects. The image analyzer represents features as small yellow crosses. Increase the number of these details in your image, and verify that the details create a non-repeating pattern.

A square contains four features for each one of its corners.

A circle contains no features as it contains no sharp or chiseled detail.

---

**1.1.2 Local contrast**

Good or bad local contrast is often difficult to detect with your eye. Improve the contrast of the image in general, or choose an image with details that are more “edged.” Organic shapes, round details, blurred, or highly-compressed images often do not provide enough richness in detail to be detected and tracked properly.

---

**1.1.3 Feature distribution**

The more balanced the distribution of the features in the image, the better the image can be detected and tracked. Verify that the yellow crosses are well-distributed across the entire image. Consider cropping the image to remove any areas without features.

---

**1.1.4 Avoid repetitive patterns**

Although some images contain enough features and good contrast, repetitive patterns hinder detection performance. For best results, choose an image without repeated motifs (even if rotated and scaled) or strong rotational symmetry. A checkerboard is an example of a repeated pattern that cannot be detected, since the 2x2 pairs of black and white squares look exactly the same and cannot be distinguished by the detector

---

**1.1.5 Rating:**

There are no features in this image because it lacks visual elements with sharp edges and high contrast. TheAR camera will fail to detect and track images that display these or similar characteristics.

---

**1.1.6 Format**

Must be 8- or 24-bit PNG and JPG formats; less than 2 MB in size; JPGs must be RGB or greyscale (no CMYK)

The AR framework we chose either Vuforia or ARToolkit does not support 3D tracking of arbitrary shapes. The angle from which it is viewed will therefore greatly affect how it looks, due to the depth, and thus whether it is recognizable or not. Because of this we have to avoid depth and consider only flat surface.

---

**1.1.7 Target Size**

Target should be at least 5 inches or 12 cm in width and of reasonable height for a good AR experience. The recommended size varies based on the actual target rating and the distance to the physical image target. Consider increasing the size of your targets if the distance of the target is higher. As a very rough "rule-of-thumb", you can get an idea of the minimum size that your target should have by dividing your camera-to-target distance by ~10. For instance, a 20 cm wide target would be typically detectable up to a distance of about 2 meters.

---

**1.1.8 Feature Exclusion Buffer**

A features-exclusion buffer surrounds the inset of an uploaded image. This buffer area is about 8% wide and it does not pick up any features, even if features do exist within that zone. See the first row of the following table, where the shaded area in red does not contain any features, even though visible features are present in this zone.

You can avoid this features-exclusion buffer situation by adding a white 8% buffer around the image for the Target Manager Target generation.

Best Of Luck...:)